# How to create conditional color in scss or css reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have css and scss file for my project, i want to change the color theme of my pages with localstorage

**this is the css file**

```
:root {
    --footerQuotesColor : yellow;
}
[data-theme="Light"] {
    --footerQuotesColor : red;
}
[data-theme="IGS"] {
    --footerQuotesColor : blue;
}
.footer-quotesColor {
    color: var(--footerQuotesColor);
}
```

**Scss file**

```
$footerQuotesColor : yellow;
$footerQuotesColor : red;
$footerQuotesColor : blue;
.footer-quotesColor {
    color: $footerQuotesColor;
}
```

how can I use this to change my color, I can't find the `js` side for the changing part

Comment: The theming is not done with colors only. You have to define CSS class hierarchy which would adjust to changes of the "theme class" in the topmost element

Answer (score 0):

In a non reactjs world this could simply be done by

```js
// 1. define theme, as a map of theme variable and value
const themeObject = {
  "Light": {
    '--footerQuotesColor': '#222',
    '--otherVariables': 'othercolor',
  },
  "IGS": {
    '--footerQuotesColor': '#DDD',
    '--otherVariables': 'othercolor',    
  },
};
// 2. Read theme from localstorage
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme'); // read theme from localstorage
// 3. Apply theme to all variables
Object.keys(themeObject[theme]).map(themeVariable => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--footerQuotesColor', themeObject[theme][themeVariable]); // this is how you set CSS variables in JS
})
```

To do this in React JS you can use styled components and here is the high level approach

1. Step 1 and 2 are same, instead of storing CSS variables as keys, use CSS property names
2. Pass theme as a react context to your app (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
3. Now inside a styled-component read theme from context and set styles accordingly.

[A nice read on smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/dark-mode-react-apps-styled-components/)